# Difference between when a networks stops training because "minimum gradient reached" and when it stops training because "validation stop"

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, matlab, validation, pattern-recognition

I'm using the neural networks functions in Matlab (`patternnet` with `trainFcn = trainlm`) to classify some data into 5 types. After running the network several times on the same datasets I realized that sometimes it stops training because "minimum gradient reached" and sometimes because "validation stop". Whenever it stops because "minimum gradient reached", the errors (mse) for training, validation and testing are very low (almost zero) and whenever it stops because "validation stop" all 3 errors are ridiculously high (anywhere from 12% to 36%). Moreover, when I increased the `max_fail` value for validation to 20 (default is 6), training stopped because "min gradient reached" every time, but the errors were low (almost 0) only when the number of validation fails was less than 6. Whenever validation fails exceeded 6, the errors were high even though training stopped because of "min gradient reached".

I need to know why this is happening.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the network getting stuck at a local minima instead of reaching the global minima?

Answer (score 0):

As you say in the comments, it sounds like your network gets stuck in a local minimum. Try playing around with the learning rate schedule! Perhaps increasing the initial learning rate or letting it decrease slower will help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but for a regression problem, where some times training was stopping due to "minimum gradient reached". 
I solved it by changing the activation function of the output layer. I was using tansig and switched to purelin.
So you can try changing the activation functions and see if it improves the model's behaviour.